# PHP Automatic Self Trigger

Tags: php

Not sure if I understood the use/purpose of PHP entirely, but what seems to me that a .php file only executes when it is being called/executed by something before it, could be a html or a php file.

A thought, is it possible that a php file written, and it would just be activated by its own, example over a duration span of time, every week or so it would do something?

Thanks for looking...

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a cron job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for a [cron job](http://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference). This allows you to save a line of code on your remote server that will execute based on the criteria you set. You can make it execute a variety of files but PHP files are definitely one of the files you can execute in this manner.

Comment: Cron if I read it correctly, you would have to create a cron.php, and then it gets invoked thru a url?

What if all you want to do is just to park the php file on the server, and it'll do the necessary?

Comment: No, there's a config in the server that sets URLs that will be called at time variables.

Comment: you can call the file anything you want. As long as php exists on the server you just put 'PHP path/to/file.php' as the command to execute in the crontab.

Comment: Most webhosts allow cron jobs from your control panel, simply have to add url to the file to be run

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by nathan, you will be looking for a [cron job](http://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference). This is a server side setting in the server that will call a url at a set interval.

You seem to not really understand how PHP works. PHP scripts are called server-side before sending data to the client. They are run once when the client is accessing the script.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that... I'm very new to this, and have been assuming a lot of things regarding how PHP works... Thanks again Christian =)